# ConnectedStreams paused until control stream "ready"

Tags: apache-flink

What is the canonical way to accomplish this:

> Given a ConnectedStreams, e.g., a CoFlatMap UDF, how to prevent any
> processing of the data stream until the control stream is "ready", so
> to speak

My particular use case is as follows: I have a CoFlatMap function. The data stream contains elements that need to be enriched with additional information (they come with some fields empty). The missing information is taken from the control stream, whose elements come through a kafka source. Essentially, what I want is to pause any processing until having read the full (control) topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pausing of one stream is not supported yet unless you go deep down the rabbit hole and implement your own operator (not recommended).

Instead, you'd cache all elements from the data stream until your control stream is fully loaded in addition to everything else in the [broadcast pattern](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/state/broadcast_state.html).

Answer (score 2):

To avoid potentially caching a lot of data from the main stream, there's another approach that can be used. Typically you use a stateful join to combine the enriching data (aka "control stream", in your question) with the main data stream. So since you have to save enriching data in state for the join, you can do an initial run of your workflow in a mode where only enriching data is being read. Once you know (e.g. via counters, or Kafka offsets) that the enriching stream has been completely loaded to state, you can take a savepoint, then restart the workflow in normal mode.

Comment: Thanks Kkrugler for your reply. It gives another perspective. In my case though, I'm more interested in a solution which does not involve multiple runs / taking snapshots, so to speak.